# Where can I find out what a given stop error means?

Tags: windows-server-2003, stoperror

I have a windows 2003 server which restarted suddenlty. The reason given is:

```
System Failure: Stop error
 Reason Code: 0x805000f
 Bug ID: :-(
 Bugcheck String: 0x000000d1 (0x00000000, 0xd0000002, 0x00000000, 0xf35e8140)
 Comment: 0x000000d1 (0x00000000, 0xd0000002, 0x00000000, 0xf35e8140)
```

Where can I find out what that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. We'd need more information to tell you where it's happening in the code. 9 times out of 10, in my life, that's been a cruddy driver.

If you're able to reproduce it every boot, try booting in Safe Mode (which loads a restricted set of services and drivers) and see how the machine acts. If you can't reproduce it in Safe Mode, start disabling devices and booting into normal mode. (Or, alternatively, learn how to pull apart the memory dump and analyze it. "Monte Carlo" driver disabling might be faster, though...)

Comment: I'm not sure what information to give. The server was going along - it has a database, a vpn connection, and a remote desktop connection was going at the time. I think it was also copying some files over that VPN connection at the time it crashed.

Comment: The "more information" I was referring to was the memory dump file iself and full contents of the STOP screen. I don't have the availability to do pro-bono memory dump analysis, but maybe someone else on here would want to download a multi-hundred-megabyte memory dump and give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Microsoft document](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=859637B4-85F1-4215-B7D0-25F32057921C&displaylang=en) on stop errors for windows 2003

Also see this [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831694)

> STOP 0x000000D1 (parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4)
>
> You experience this problem on a computer that uses an integrated device electronics (IDE) controller, and the IDE controller requires synchronization across all channels.

A hotfix is available from the kb article.